# Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(AuthScreen)"

Tags: react-native

Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(AuthScreen)". Either wrap the root component in a , or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(AuthScreen)".

How do i do that . Getting literaly confused.
[image: error from emulator]

here is my code for AuthScreen

```
    import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import * as actions from "../actions";

class AuthScreen extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.facebookLogin();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>AuthScreen</Text>
        <Text>AuthScreen</Text>
        <Text>AuthScreen</Text>
        <Text>AuthScreen</Text>
        <Text>AuthScreen</Text>
        <Text>AuthScreen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(null, actions) (AuthScreen);
```

and this is App.js

```
 import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

import store from "./store";
import WelcomeScreen from './screens/WelcomeScreen';
import AuthScreen from './screens/AuthScreen';
import DeckScreen from "./screens/DeckScreen";
import MapScreen from "./screens/MapScreen";
import ReviewScreen from "./screens/ReviewScreen";
import SettingsScreen from "./screens/SettingsScreen";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {

    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <MainNavigation />
        </View>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
export default  MainNavigation = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Welcome: WelcomeScreen,
  auth: AuthScreen,
  main: createBottomTabNavigator({
    map: MapScreen,
    deck: DeckScreen,
    review: createStackNavigator({
      review: ReviewScreen,
      settings: SettingsScreen
    })
  })

});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Try    
  `state = {
    isLoading: true,
    store: configureStore(() => {
      this.setState({ isLoading: false });
      // NativeModules.SplashScreen.hide();
    })
  };`  `<Provider store={this.state.store}>
  <AppNavigator />
  </Provider>`

Comment: In which screen should i add the code and where can you be specific

Comment: In your App.js file make a state : {} as mention in above comment and put your Provider in <View> just like :     `<View style = {{flex:1}}> <Provider  store = {this.state.store}> </Provider> </View>`

Comment: not working .showing configureStore error

Answer (score 0):

In App.js, MainNavigation is being exported instead of App, which is the component with the Provider. It seems like App isn't being rendered at all, so the default export should be move to App to include the Provider when this file is executed. Then Redux will be able to see your store.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {

    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <MainNavigation />
        </View>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
const MainNavigation = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Welcome: WelcomeScreen,
  auth: AuthScreen,
  main: createBottomTabNavigator({
    map: MapScreen,
    deck: DeckScreen,
    review: createStackNavigator({
      review: ReviewScreen,
      settings: SettingsScreen
    })
  })

});
```

Comment: the emulator screen is giving blank white screen output and nothing is happening.

Comment: That issue seems unrelated, it's probably with a parent component.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you've a navigator in which only `App` component uses the `Provider`, but there's no `App` in the structure of your app.

Please consult the documentation once more - https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/redux-integration.html - to chck how it shuold work.

The solution most likelly is what Nick proposes but you need to have a `Home` route specifed, or set the proper `initialRouteName` option (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html)